# Show as blank rather than 0.00% (Decimal showing as %)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

How can I set the calculated formula on SharePoint list when the result is 0 (0.00%) to show as a blank and if there is a value do the following calculation `=Figure/100`?

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you add the current formula you are using to your question?

Comment: Are you trying to do this? `=IF(ISBLANK([Figure]),"",[Figure]/100)`

Comment: How stupid am i haha, you are a legend. This worked

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept my below response as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 1):

Try using calculated column formula like this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Figure]),"",[Figure]/100)
```

**Notes**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.